# How to make the main thread wait for the other threads to complete in ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I am using the ThreadPoolExecutor to implement threading in my Java Application.

I have a XML which I need to parse and add each node of it to a thread to execute the completion. My implementation is like this:

parse_tp is a threadpool object created & ParseQuotesXML is the class with the run method.

```
        try {     
           List children = root.getChildren();               
        Iterator iter = children.iterator();

        //Parsing the XML     
        while(iter.hasNext()) {       
           Element child = (Element) iter.next();           
           ParseQuotesXML quote = new ParseQuotesXML(child, this);         
           parse_tp.execute(quote);         
        }
    System.out.println("Print it after all the threads have completed");
        catch(Exception ex) {  
        ex.printStackTrace();      
        }
        finally {  
    System.out.println("Print it in the end.");
if(!parse_tp.isShutdown()) {
                if(parse_tp.getActiveCount() == 0 && parse_tp.getQueue().size() == 0 ) {
                    parse_tp.shutdown();                    
                } else {
                    try {
                        parse_tp.awaitTermination(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        log.info("Exception while terminating the threadpool "+ex.getMessage());
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
          parse_tp.shutdown();  
        }
```

The problem is, the two print out statements are printed before the other threads exit. I want to make the main thread wait for all other threads to complete. 
In normal Thread implementation I can do it using join() function but not getting a way to achieve the same in ThreadPool Executor. Also would like to ask if the code written in finally block to close the threadpool proper ?

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your second question, I think you are doing a reasonable job trying to clean up your thread pool.

With respect to your first question, I think the method that you want to use is [submit](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService.html#submit%28java.util.concurrent.Callable%29) rather than `execute`.  Rather than try to explain it all in text, here's an edited fragment from a unit test that I wrote that makes many tasks, has each of them do a fragment of the total work and then meets back at the starting point to add the results:

```
final AtomicInteger messagesReceived = new AtomicInteger(0);

// ThreadedListenerAdapter is the class that I'm testing 
// It's not germane to the question other than as a target for a thread pool.
final ThreadedListenerAdapter<Integer> adapter = 
    new ThreadedListenerAdapter<Integer>(listener);
int taskCount = 10;

List<FutureTask<Integer>> taskList = new ArrayList<FutureTask<Integer>>();

for (int whichTask = 0; whichTask < taskCount; whichTask++) {
    FutureTask<Integer> futureTask = 
        new FutureTask<Integer>(new Callable<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer call() throws Exception {
            // Does useful work that affects messagesSent
            return messagesSent;
        }
    });
    taskList.add(futureTask);
}

for (FutureTask<Integer> task : taskList) {
    LocalExecutorService.getExecutorService().submit(task);
}

for (FutureTask<Integer> task : taskList) {
    int result = 0;
    try {
        result = task.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("ExecutionException in task " + task, ex);
    }
    assertEquals(maxMessages, result);
}

int messagesSent = taskCount * maxMessages;
assertEquals(messagesSent, messagesReceived.intValue());
```

I think this fragment is similar to what you're trying to do.  The key components were the [submit](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService.html#submit%28java.util.concurrent.Callable%29) and [get](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html#get%28%29) methods.

Answer (score 4):

A [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) is designed for this very purpose. Examples may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11372932/230513) and [here](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.java.programmer/msg/1d9c821dcda040f6). When the number of threads is not known in advance, consider a [`Phaser`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html), new in Java 1.7, or an [`UpDownLatch`](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.java.programmer/browse_frm/thread/2342bd25ac3dd6b9).

Comment: Thanks trashgod, but I dont have a exact count of the nodes of xml which I need to parse, so wont be able to use CountDownLatch. But I wasn't aware of any such property available in Java, so thanks a lot for this.

Comment: Excellent. As suggested above, `Future` is more flexible, but I added a link to an UpDownLatch example, too.

Comment: Note that a _Phaser_ has a limit of maximal count of 65535. Not sure if there is a simple workaround.

Comment: The [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html) suggests _tiering_.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can use [ThreadPoolExecutor.submit()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService.html#submit%28java.util.concurrent.Callable%29) method, which returns Future instance, then after you submitted all your work items you can iterate trough those futures and call [Future.get()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) on each of them.

Alternatively, you can prepare your runnable work items and submit them all at once using [ThreadPoolExecutor.invokeAll()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection%29), which will wait until all work items completed and then you can get the execution results or exception calling the same Future.get() method.

Comment: `ThreadPoolExecutor.invokeAll()` operates on `Callable<T>` objects.  Is there a convenience method that can achieve the same result for `Runnable` objects that don't produce any result?