# Java Applet JOptionPane and setSize issue

Tags: java, swing, applet, awt, joptionpane

I'll start by saying that I'm a bit new to java, so if it's a stupid mistake, that's the reason.

I was messing with applets in java, and I've run into a problem when setting the size of the window, and using JOptionPane, whether it's just showing a message, or getting input through it, it displays three or more panes, rather than simply one. I'm on Ubuntu 12.04(x64), and here is my test code that still encounters the problem:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.applet.Applet;

public class Main extends Applet{

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        //setup screen size
        setSize((int)500,(int)500);
        //print test message
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There Should Be One Of Me!");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's expected: there are as many option panes as number of calls to the paint method :-) the latter is not controllable by application code, neither in AWT nor in Swing. Never-ever change any component state in methods called during the paint cycle.

Comment: Ok, thats the answer I was looking for, if you could put that in an answer, that would be great...

Comment: *"I was messing with applets in java, and I've run into a problem when setting the size of the window"* That will not work reliably in the web page.  Abandon it and try something useful. And use a `JApplet`.  Either that or make it a `JFrame` and launch the frame from a link using [JWS](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: ok, I will definately do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's expected: there are as many option panes as number of calls to the paint method :-) the latter is not controllable by application code, neither in AWT nor in Swing.

As a general rule, never-ever change any component state in methods called during the paint cycle

Answer (score 0):

1. remove `setSize(..` and `JOptionPane.sh...` from `public void paint(Graphics g)`
2. [for Applet I miss there method init()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/getStarted.html)
3. [(J)Applet tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/index.html) shows a few examples
4. maybe better could be to use [Swing JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) instead of `(J)Applet`

Comment: For reference, there's a hybrid applet/application [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11372932/230513).

Comment: not sure what's wrong, maybe temperature in the Central Europe ???, hmmm but I love > 32 degrees by Celsius to much

Comment: aaaach I seeeeeeeee too much links to the external sites :-)

Comment: no, too many (all except the first) unrelated bullets. Still trying to nudge you into staying focused on the problem at hand instead of mentioning whatever comes to your mind :-)