# Should your class implement ActionListener or use an object of an anonymous ActionListener class

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

What's the best way for implementing the `java.awt.event.ActionListener` interface?

Have your class implement ActionListener and add this as an ActionListener:

```
class Foo implements ActionListener{

    public Foo() {
        JButton button = new JButton();
        button.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }
}
```

Or add an object of an anonymous ActionListener class:

```
class Foo{

    public Foo() {
        JButton button = new JButton();
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {     
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Some (jeanette/kleopatra) say to almost *never* use ActionListener, and to instead use Actions such as an AbstractAction. It's almost always a bad ideal to have your GUI class implement your listeners though as this breaks the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and makes your code more difficult to maintain and extend,and  so I strongly urge you not to do that.

So for example, an inner class for this:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;

class Foo {

   public Foo() {
       JButton button = new JButton(new ButtonAction("Action", KeyEvent.VK_A));
   }

   private class ButtonAction extends AbstractAction {
      public ButtonAction(String name, Integer mnemonic) {
         super(name);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         System.out.println("button pressed");
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: +1 For `AbstractAction` and [`Single Responsibility Principle`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Comment: Nice, but it seems to be more complex (in code maintaining terms), and more difficult to read. Or I'm wrong?

Comment: It gets easy to read as you get more familiar with it. I've used it when I've tried to maintain a well separated MVC pattern, and have had my Control inject Actions into my JButtons.

Comment: And don't forget, easier to test. You can simply test the action class when it is not tied to your UI

Comment: Related example—and constructive review in comments—[here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11372932/230513).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels how do you manage the dependencies when an Action is used by 2 different Controllers ? Would you create separate actions ? (I understand the goal is to use the same action in different contexts) And, I may need knowledge about my view or my controller. I had created Actions used in different controllers but had serious dependencies problems so went back to inner class in the view

Answer (score 8):

The second option (anonymous class) is certainly better, another option would be to have a nested class within `Foo`.

I wouldn't go with the first option for two reasons:

- The users of `Foo` shouldn't have to know that it implements `ActionListener`.
- You cannot implement two different listeners in the same class.

Comment: I would upvote this answer for the first reason, but the second reason is just wrong imho. You can check the source of the `ActionEvent` and decide the code path you should take. Whether that is an elegant solution is another discussion, but it is certainly possible

Comment: @Robin: You're right but that was not my point. What I meant is that one wouldn't be able to implement the `ActionListener` twice in the same class.

Answer (score 4):

It depends. If you want to reuse the `ActionListener` across multiple components, option one is better. If the `ActionListener` will only ever be associated with the one button, option two is fine.

Generally, you would create a separate class (or inner class), if you anticipate some growth in the project. There's no need for `Foo` to implement `ActionListener`.

Comment: Having a gui class implement ActionListener is only for toy programs. Since he's asking about "best practices" then there is no use of this in any circumstances.