# ActionListener best practices

Tags: java, swing, package, actionlistener

Sorry for the title, probably too generic.

I already read [How to Write an Action Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) tutorial by Java and I already read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438048/best-practice-for-implementing-actionlistener), but I still have some doubts: I was wondering which solution is the best when I have to perform the same action multiple time.

I'd want to reuse the same `ActionListener`, but I am not sure on how to achieve this in the best way (speaking in term of: code readability, code mantainability, performance and code style).

First the "standard" code (which I would use if I'm not going to reuse the action listener):

```
btnMenu.addActionListener(
    new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Navigator.showMenu();
        }
    }
);
```

This way I can't reuse anything obv, since it's an anonymous inner class...

Now, I can think of the following solutions:

1. Store a reference of an Anonymous Inner Class in a field (that will most likely be `static final`);
2. Write a new class that implements `ActionListener` interface.

Example code for solution 1:

```
public static final MENU_ACTION_LISTENER = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Navigator.showMenu();
    }
};

btnMenu.addActionListener(MENU_ACTION_LISTENER);
```

Example code for solution 2:

```
// package-private, only GUI-package classes should be able to use it.
// most likely I won't ever need to subclass it, so why not making it final?
final class MenuActionListener implements ActionListener  {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Navigator.showMenu();
    }
}

// now, wherever I need to use it:
btnMenu.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
```

I have some doubts about both solutions:

1. Where to store references to Anonymous Action Listeners? I could have a sort of utility class (e.g. `ActionListenersUtil`) where store all action listeners I want to reuse in `static final` fields, but I don't like it... it seems to me poor design.
2. It makes more sense, probably best follows the [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)... I initially had some doubt about the packages... I'd like to have all listeners in a separate package (e.g. `com.myapp.gui` for gui elements and `com.myapp.gui.listeners` for listeners. But when I wrote down this I realized that I have no choice: the only place where it make sense is in the same package (because they *must* be package-private), even if for the sake of order I would have like to put them all in a separate package.
   I still have some doubt though, because most action listeners may be reusable even in case GUI changes; it still would be a good idea to have it in the same package?

Another question: what's the difference between calling `btnMenu.addActionListener(MENU_ACTION_LISTENER);` and `btnMenu.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());` (speaking in term of JVM, class loading, class compiling, memory occupied by each class, garbage collection and so on)?

Please help, I'm so confused right now! :(

Answer (score 14):

The best way is to create an `Action` instead of an `ActionListener` if you have to attach it to buttons, menus, ... . An `Action` is the model of a `JButton`, and the model is meant to be shared

This also gives you the ability to change the text, icon, enabled status, and other properties of all the buttons that the `Action` is attached to at the same time without multiple calls. Plus, it can be attached to menu items and such as well.

To create an `Action` you do not have to start from scratch. [`AbstractAction`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractAction.html) is a good starting point. The [Swing `Action` tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) is also a good read.

Comment: +1 This also gives you the ability to change the text, icon, enabled status, and other properties of all the buttons that the `Action` is attached to at the same time without multiple calls. Plus, it can be attached to menu items and such as well.

Comment: @Brian very good remark. I copy-pasted it in the answer to make it more complete

Comment: @Robin Thanks! Wish I could +1 twice. `Action` is one of the most underused classes in Swing, IMO.

Comment: oh shi-! I'm a little too late for that! :|  Inexperience can do bad jokes... unfortunately now I cannot change everything, is there an elegant way to go with `ActionListener`s?