# Draw Rectangle on pressing JButton

Tags: java, swing

I am currently working on a little game but I just encountered a problem:

I have three classes, the first one is the JFrame:

```
public class Game 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Game().gui();
    }


    public void gui()
    {
        DrawPanel panel = new DrawPanel();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        //frame.add(panel); 
        frame.add(new MainMenu());
        frame.setSize(800, 700);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
    }
}
```

Now I have two other classes, one is the mainMenu, currently consisting of just one JButton.
I decided to make the menu its own class because later, I want to call the menu by pressing escape, but the problem is that (for testing reasons) I want to draw an rectangle when "start" is pressed. I tried different approaches but nothing happens.

```
public class MainMenu extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{

     GamePanel panel = new GamePanel();

     public MainMenu()
     {

         setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
         GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

         JButton b1 = new JButton("Start");
         c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
         c.ipadx = 200;

         b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
         {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                setVisible(false);
            }
         });
         add(b1, c);

     }

}


public class DrawPanel extends JPanel
{

     public void paint(Graphics g) 
          {
            g.drawRect (10, 10, 200, 200);  
          }

}
```

Comment: You have `//frame.add(panel);`, so there is nothing drawn...

Comment: I know. But it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: I think you should `@Override` the `paintComponent` method. You can see [custom painting in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/). Your button listener is a separate issue than currently drawing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors I found in your code:

1. You're not adding your `DrawPanel` to anything because this line

   ```
   frame.add(panel);
   ```

   is commented, so, that leads us to the next problem:
2. You're overriding `paint()` method instead of [`paintComponent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics)) and also don't forget to call

   ```
   super.paintComponent();
   ```

   at the very beginning of the method. Without it, you're preventing your code to keep painting the rest of the components. See [Custom painting in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
3. That still doesn't makes anything appear because you haven't declared a location for your `DrawPanel` and thus it's taking `JFrame`'s default [Layout Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) which is [`BorderLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) and it's default location when not specified is `CENTER`, and as you're adding `new MainMenu()` to it on the same position it replaces the `DrawPanel` panel, since only one component can exist on the same position.

   Instead try and place the `DrawPanel` to the `CENTER` and the `MainMenu` to the `SOUTH`. It now should look like this:

   [image]
4. Don't forget to place your program on the [Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) by writing your `main` method as follows:

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               //Your constructor here
           }
       });
   }
   ```
5. You're implementing `ActionListener` on `MainMenu` but not implementing it's methods, remove it or implement the `actionPerformed` method and move the code inside the `b1` action listener to it. However I highly recommend you to take at [Should your class implement ActionListener or use an object of an anonymous ActionListener class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438048/should-your-class-implement-actionlistener-or-use-an-object-of-an-anonymous-acti) too
6. You're playing with `MainMenu`'s `JPanel` visibility, instead you should try using a [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) or consider using [`JDialog`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

   For example I would make a `JDialog` and place the `JButton` there, so it will open the `JFrame` with the `Rectangle` drawn in it.

Now, the code that made the above output and follows all recommendations (but #6) is:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Game().gui();
            }
        });
    }

    public void gui() {
        DrawPanel panel = new DrawPanel();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(new MainMenu(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
    }
}

class MainMenu extends JPanel  {

//  GamePanel panel = new GamePanel();

    public MainMenu() {

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        JButton b1 = new JButton("Start");
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.ipadx = 200;

        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        add(b1, c);
    }
}

class DrawPanel extends JPanel {

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawRect(10, 10, 200, 200);
    }
}
```

---

As suggested in the comments by @MadProgrammer, you can also override the `getPreferredSize()` method of your `DrawPanel` and then call `frame.pack()`:

Your  `DrawPanel` class should now look like this:

```
class DrawPanel extends JPanel {

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawRect(10, 10, 200, 200);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(400, 300);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd also suggest overriding `getPreferredSize` of the `DrawPanel`, it will provide additional layout hints which can help, nice answer otherwise ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer thank you, I edited the answer to add your recommendation, could you check it and tell me if it was what you were referring to?

Comment: Thank you for answering, it helped a lot. Now, one more little Question: I solved the Problem with the appearing of the rectangle by adding add(new DrawPanel()); in b1.addActionListener. Now it works fine, but I think this is a strange solution.

Comment: @JonDoeMaths Well, yes, instead do as I said before, make use of a `CardLayout` which contains 2 (or many) cards, 1 with the `JButton` that on click will make the 2nd card with the rectangle appear, if you want that question answered with a proper code, be sure to ask a new question and provide a valid [mcve]