# how can I make this class an applet

Tags: java, swing, applet

I have the following class which is a simple gui, and I would like to make it an applet so it can be displayed in the browser. I know how to embed the code into an html page(got that done)... but how can make my class an applet? Also, I assuming I don't need a web server just to display the applet in my browser...

```
package tester1;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class PanelTest implements ActionListener {

    JFrame frame;
    JLabel inputLabel;
    JLabel outputLabel;
    JLabel outputHidden;
    JTextField inputText;
    JButton button;
    JButton clear;
    JButton about;

    public PanelTest() {
       frame = new JFrame("User Name");
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2, 10, 10));

       //creating first row
       JPanel row1 = new JPanel();
       inputLabel = new JLabel("Your Name");
       inputText = new JTextField(15);
//       FlowLayout flow1 = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 10, 10);
//       row1.setLayout(flow1);
       row1.add(inputLabel);
       row1.add(inputText);
       frame.add(row1);
       //creating second row
       JPanel row2 = new JPanel();
       button = new JButton("Display");
       clear = new JButton("Clear");
       about = new JButton("About");
       button.addActionListener(this);
       clear.addActionListener(this);
       about.addActionListener(new displayAbout());
       row2.add(button);
       row2.add(clear);
       row2.add(about);
       frame.add(row2);
       //creating third row
       JPanel row3 = new JPanel();
       outputLabel = new JLabel("Output:", JLabel.LEFT);
       outputHidden = new JLabel("", JLabel.RIGHT);
//       FlowLayout flow2 = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 10, 10);
//       row3.setLayout(flow2);
       row3.add(outputLabel);
       row3.add(outputHidden);
       frame.add(row3); 

       frame.pack();
       frame.setVisible(true);

    }  

    //same method listen for two different events
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String command = e.getActionCommand();
        if(command.equals("Display")) {
            outputHidden.setText(inputText.getText());
        }
        if(command.equals("Clear")) {
            outputHidden.setText("");
            inputText.setText("");
        }        
    }

    //another way to listen for events
    class displayAbout implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Username 1.1 \n by Jorge L. Vazquez");
        }
    }    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PanelTest frameTest = new PanelTest();
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to read the [applet tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/index.html), pure and simple. Sorry, but your post isn't an answerable question other than that it's time to do your studying. Voting to close.

Comment: *"I would like to make it an applet"*  Inadvisable.  Instead, launch the app. from a link using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: See also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11479113/230513).

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`JApplet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JApplet.html) rather than a `JFrame`. Make sure you read [the relevant Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html), which covers the applet lifecycle methods like `init`, `start`, `stop`, and `destroy`.

---

As a side note, you should **not** be building your UI outside of the event dispatch thread.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `JApplet` instead of a `JFrame` like veer said, but you must also remove `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`, `frame.pack();`, and `frame.setVisible(true);`

Also, replace `main(String[] args)` with `init()`.

Comment: and when is it that I need to extend JApplets class

Comment: you change `frame` to a JApplet.

Comment: netbeans is giving error "class panelTest does not have a main method"

Comment: you have to run it as an applet, not an application.

Comment: I saved it, and embed the .class file, but still not showing the applet... I got javafx plugin installed!

Comment: Oh, I see the problem. Your main class has to extend `JApplet` so the main class is an applet; then the `init` method is in the applet class.

Comment: @miatech: you need to read the applet tutorial -- it's all explained there. Please come back if you have an actual question after you've gone through the tutorial.