# Want a JDialog to be "modal" but not block other windows

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jdialog, modality

I'm working on a program that traverses a list of objects every pass through. When an object's "time" (i.e. number of passes) is up, it brings up a JDialog to request its next task. The problem is how to deal with multiple objects making this request on a single pass.

If I make the JDialog modal, each object makes its request in turn, which is what I want; but the main program window is unavailable, which I do not want.

If the JDialog is not modal, multiple instances appear, one for each pass, which I do not want; or, if I set it up as a singleton, only one instance appears but only the last object int the list to make the request gets to use it.

Is there a way I can pop up the dialog, leave other windows available to the user, and have the other objects wait their turn to use the dialog?

Comment: Looks like you need some sort of queue. It might help if you posted some of your code.

Comment: Aaron, the objects are in a queue of sorts already. I just don't know how to make them wait until the JDialog closes/hides before advancing the queue.

Comment: use a queue as noted and a WindowListener.

Comment: Solved by setting the original window's Modal Exclusion Type to "Application" and toggling back to "No Exclude" before opening other, "fully" modal dialogs.

Comment: @flibbertygibbet: If that solved it, you can post it as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in comments, the problem can be addressed by altering the [*modality*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html) of the parent `Window`. On the downside, the "behavior is implementation-dependent."

As an alternative, consider traversing the objects in the background thread of a `SwingWorker` and adding new candidates to a suitable component, e.g. `JList`, `JTable`, or `JTabbedPane`. Selecting an element form the component would bring up a conventional modal dialog, removing the element on completion. A related example is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11372932/230513). Each of the suggested components can be labeled with an icon representing its status.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by setting the original window's ModalExclusionType to "application" and toggling back to "no exclude" once finished.