# Jtable is not adding row in runtime

Tags: java

Im trying to add a row during runtime but it keeps breaking. This is just a simple test to get everything working. It only will show everything once it has added everything to the table, but sits with a black window until then.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
    JFrame dashboard = new JFrame("Dashboard");
    dashboard.setVisible(true); 
    dashboard.setTitle("Dashboard Information");
    dashboard.setBounds((960 - 250), (540 - 250), 500, 500);

    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    JTable table = new JTable(model);
    dashboard.add(new JScrollPane(table));

    model.addColumn("Col2");
    model.addColumn("Col1");
    model.addColumn("Col3");
    model.addRow(new Object[] {"test", 1, "test"});
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        model.addRow(new Object[] {"test2", 2, "test2"});
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }

    dashboard.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    dashboard.pack();

    }
```

Comment: Well, you're violating the single threaded nature of the API to begin with

Comment: works fine for me.. may be your system is taking too long to render it.. try changing to `Thread.sleep(2000);` to give it time to render.. also move the last 2 statements before the for-loop because you're blocking the main thread

Comment: [As a more accurate example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17414109/populate-jtable-with-large-number-of-rows/17415635#17415635) this will allow add rows to the table from a background thread, in away that does not violate the single threaded nature of the API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `Jframe` is only packed after we add the rows which means that the table does not appear because we have not made it yet! Moving the `dashboard.pack()` or the `Jframe.pack()` to above the loop and below the `dashboard.add(new JScrollPane(table));` first makes the table so it exists, then correctly adds rows during runtime.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
    JFrame dashboard = new JFrame("Dashboard");
    dashboard.setVisible(true); 
    dashboard.setTitle("Dashboard Information");
    dashboard.setBounds((960 - 250), (540 - 250), 500, 500);

    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    JTable table = new JTable(model);
    dashboard.add(new JScrollPane(table));
    //move lines to here
    dashboard.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    dashboard.pack();

    model.addColumn("Col2");
    model.addColumn("Col1");
    model.addColumn("Col3");
    model.addRow(new Object[] {"test", 1, "test"});
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        model.addRow(new Object[] {"test2", 2, "test2"});
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
    //put these lines beofore we add rows to the table
    //dashboard.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //dashboard.pack();

    }
```