# Java: Proper way to update TableModel's data?

Tags: java, swing, list, events, defaulttablemodel

This is a simplifed version of what I'm trying to do.  I have a map which maps an integer id to a list of strings.  One of these lists from the map is displayed by a JTable at all times.  (Depending on which id needs to be displayed)  All information for the map is coming from a database, and is constantly being added to and removed from.
My DataClass which stores the full map and receives the updates from the database:

```
DataClass {
   Map(Integer, List<String>) map;

   // TabelModel gets list here
   public List<String> getList(int id) {
       return map.get(id);
   }

   // Updates from database come here
   public updateList(int id, String info) {
       if (map.containsKey(id) {
          map.get(id).add(info);
       }
       else {
          map.put(id, new List<String>(info));
       }
   }

   // Remove from list, etc all down here
   ...
}
```

My Table model class:

```
MyTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {
    List data;

    public void updateData(int id) {
        data = getList(id)
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    ... All the other stuff needed ...
}
```

Since database updates occur in batches, I know that at the end of a batch I have to update the table.  So the DataClass informs the UI class which informs the table to update.  This causes the `updateData(id)` to be called which retrieves a new set of data from the DataClass and calls `fireTableDataChanged();`

My Question are:

1. Is this the right way to go about updating/storing the data in the table?
2. Should getList return a clone of the data?  If I just return the reference all updates from the database would be accessing that same reference and since these updates aren't running in the EDT wouldn't that be bad/frowned upon/wrong?
3. How can I do this using Java Events?  PropertyChangeEvent?  If so, how?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

To the extent that your questions are related,

1. No; when new data is available, your `updateData()` method should update the internal data structure of your [`TableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) and fire an appropriate event; because `DefaultTableModel` knows nothing of your `List`, extend `AbstractTableModel`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17384208/230513); the `JTable` will update itself in response.
2. No; your database access layer should retain no references to queried objects, and no cloning should be necessary; forward queried objects to your display layer from the `process()` method of `SwingWorker`, or similar.
3. Use a [`TableModelListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/tablemodellistener.html) to learn when and how the `TableModel` has changed; update the database accordingly.