# Update Thread in applet

Tags: java, swing, awt, awt-eventqueue

In my application i have created multiple Threads, In that in each thread value has been changed. so every minute i want update all threads the same value from the list..In this coding, values are not updated. previous values only retained in every thread. What is the solution?

```
public static class updateClient implements Runnable {
    public static void doUpadte(Map<String, String> list) {
        final Map<String, String> liHashMap = list;
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                for (Entry<String, String> entry : liHashMap.entrySet()) {
                    String client_Name=entry.getKey();
                    taNames.append(client_Name + "\n");
                }       
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while(true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                doUpadte(list);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please why is there SwingWorkers tag, don't see that be used,

Comment: and workers Thread invoked from Runnable#Thread is more logical and easier that the same made in SwingWorker

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Maybe something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11372932/230513)?