# CountDownLatch leads to disappearance of content in JFrame (JButtons, etc.) and comes back only when mouse overed

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, synchronization, jframe

I am working on Deal or No Deal with a user interface. The first problem I ran into was how to wait for a button action to continue, and I used Count Down Latches and it worked perfectly. But whenever, I click a button, everything in my JFrame disappears and comes back when you mouse over, it all of a sudden reappears when I press another buttton (This never happened before I used Count Down Latches, and this also happens with Semaphores, etc.) I'll try to keep my code as relevant as possible.

```
    public CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch(1);
    pickFirst();
    try {
        cdl.await();
    } catch (Exception E) {
    }
    while (banker.findCasesLeft() > 2) {
        banker = new Banker(Main.f.values);

        for (i = casesToPick; i >= 1; i--) {
            cdl = new CountDownLatch(1);
            pickCase();
            picked = false;
            try {
                cdl.await();
            } catch (Exception E) {
            }
        }
```

^^^ That was my class that deals with picking cases Below is class with actionlisteners

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    if (!Main.me.pickedFirst) {
        Main.me.pickedCase = caseNo;
        Main.f.log += "You picked to keep case " + caseNo + ".\n";
        setText(caseNo + "\np");
        Main.f.changeLog();
        Main.me.pickedFirst = true;
        Main.me.cdl.countDown();
    } else {
        int value = Main.me.values[caseNo-1];
        Main.me.values[caseNo] = 0;
        Main.f.values[getIndex(value)].setSelected(true);
        Main.f.log += "You picked to get rid of case " + caseNo + ". It contained $" + value + ".\n";
        Main.f.changeLog();
        Main.me.picked = true;
        Main.me.cdl.countDown();
    }
    setEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: WIthout a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's impossible to know exactly what the problem might be.  However `Main.x` scares me as it suggests that much of your program is based on the use of `static`, not to mention a complete lack of access control...

Comment: Will it still be a problem if I'm only using one?

Comment: Also, what else do I need to add to show the problem?

Comment: I have no idea?  What happens if you change the reference to one of those `static` variables?  What's stopping any other part of your program from doing the same?

Comment: Check the [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) link, it will tell you everything you need to know

Comment: I have fixed the problem. All I had to do was unload the butttons from my JFrame and add them back again. Thanks for the help.

Comment: That would be raising the dead in my mind if I found my self faced with the solution, something is very wrong...

Comment: Updates to the UI shouldn't require to have to re-build the output, the screen going blank isn't a normal state of the UI to go through, there is something seriously wrong with how your UI is working

Comment: Maybe its because the bottom class extended a JButton and that is being added to the JFrame? Sorry if I let that out to confuse you.

Comment: *"Sorry if I let that out to confuse you."*  If you had posted a MCTaRE as advised by @MadProgrammer in their first comment, we could have known that since it was posted.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the `await()` method of [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) "Causes the current thread to wait until the latch has counted down to zero." If that thread is the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), GUI updates will be blocked until the wait condition changes. In general, `CountDownLatch` is meant to allow separate threads to rendezvous; it should't be used to within the event dispatch thread. This complete [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11372932/230513), which coordinates multiple `SwingWorker` instances, may help clarify the usage.

Comment: As an alternative, consider the MVC approach examined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513).