# How to find out where in my Java app a thread is still running using the Netbeans 8 profiler?

Tags: java, multithreading, netbeans, profiler

In my Java app I'm using ExecutorService to start and shutdown threads, but when the app is done, some threads are still running, so I used Netbeans[8] profiler to see why so I can terminate them, but as you can see from the attached chart, there are lots of them still running and I don't know where in my app these threads started, I double clicked and right clicked on the threads, nothing happened, I guess there must be a way to get to my code from the chart, can someone tell me how ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Many implementations of [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) manage a thread pool. Your instance has several threads in the [`WAITING`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html#WAITING) state, perhaps as a result of invoking `LockSupport.park()`. The [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) illustrates a common shutdown approach, which you can tailor to your use.

Addendum: As a concrete example, this [`WorkerLatchTest`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11372932/230513) creates a pool of `N = 8` worker threads. Double click on a thread in the timeline to see details about the thread.

[image]