# How to check in swingworker if all threads are done

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker

I'm wondering if there is a way to check in Swingworker (possibly in doBackground),if all threads are done.

I have an event I would like to execute but at the moment it executes at the end of each thread rather than when all threads are done.

Is there a way of checking if there are no more threads to execute so I can execute my second event?

Thanks

Comment: you should overide done method in swingworker

Comment: Do you know how many are started? In that case, using `done` in conjunction with a CountdownLatch may be for you? Or even a simple shared counter that will start the second Event as soon as counter reaches 0 in `done`.

Comment: @Abihabi87 Does done() check when one thread is done, or all of them?

Comment: @Fildor It can vary

Comment: So you don't start all of them at once. There could be 3 running already and then a 4th is started? Or is it more like you start sometimes 3 at once and want to wait for those 3 some other time you start 5 ...

Comment: @Fildor's is correct, an example using `CountDownLatch` is shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11372932/230513). If this is not a duplicate, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.