# Java swing concurrency, multiple propertychangelisteners?

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, swingworker, java-threads

I have a panel called DataPanel which extends JPanel, and a worker called DataPanelWorker which extends SwingWorker.

Currently when I create the DataPanel, I start the DataPanelWorker which does some calculations and fires property changes after each calculation.

The DataPanel listens for these property changes and displays a message each time.
e.g. 
"Calculation 1 complete"
"Calculation 2 complete"

This works fine!

What I now want to do now is create a second instance of DataPanel (let's call this DataPanel2) but I want to use the original DataPanelWorker to save computation. I register DataPanel2 as another propertyChangeListener on DataPanelWorker.

My problem is I might register DataPanel2 after calculation 1 has been completed and the first propertyChangeEvent has been fired. 
How can I know how far through the worker is so that I can get DataPanel2 to be displaying the same messages as DataPanel1?

What I would like ideally is to keep a queue of propertyChangeEvents and when registering a new component, fire them all on just that component. Is there a standard way of doing this? Or am I looking at it from the wrong view?

Thanks

Comment: Why not have the worker hold a List of state changes, and simply query the state of this list?

Comment: I'm worried about events being fired in the nanosecond between finishing looking at this list, and registering the new listener. Presumably you'd register the listener after looking at the events, if we did it before, we might get events twice.

Comment: Is there a way to pause the doInBackground() thread in order to build the second panel from this list, making sure we don't miss any property changes?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: I'm wary of synchronizing access to the list; I'd update a single `DataModel` as outlined below.

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually, your `SwingWorker` should `publish()` interim instances of `Calculation` so that `process()` can update your `DataModel` and notify any listeners.

```
class DataPanelWorker extends SwingWorker<List<Calculation>, Calculation> {…}
class DataModel {
    private List<Calculation> list = new ArrayList<>();
    …
}
```

Your implementation of `process()` can then update your `DataModel` on the *event dispatch thread*. In this way, your `DataModel` always has the complete state of the calculation. Any listening `DataPanel` can ask the `DataModel` for the current `List<Calculation>` to display. Your `DataModel` can notify listeners of the arrival of new data using any of the approaches shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513). This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4637725/230513) updates a `JLabel`; this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13205322/230513) also updates a chart; this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25526869/230513) updates the `TableModel` of a listening `JTable`.

> `DataPanelWorker`…does some calculations and fires property changes after each calculation.

Avoid firing property change events in your implementation of `doInBackground()`, as access to any shared data will need to be synchronized independently of the worker. Instead, update your `DataModel` in your implementation of `process()`, which synchronizes access for you. The `DataModel` can then fire events for registered listeners, knowing that updates will happen on the *event dispatch thread*.

> Is there a way to pause the `doInBackground()` thread?

It's permitted, but you should't have to do so in this context. If necessary, multiple workers can cooperate as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11372932/230513).

Comment: I like this idea. This way the list is only manipulated, read or written to, on one thread.

Comment: Yes this makes much more sense. I hadn't thought to have a DataModel. Much better - thanks!

Comment: @DuaneAllman: It's common in Swing [architecture](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/architecture-142923.html). You'll want to work through some examples, but you may be able to reuse your property change events in the `DataModel`.